# Graphical glitch using JCrop

Tags: javascript, html, jcrop

I'm having serious troubles implementing Jcrop. I'll show the code regarding Jcrop implementation:

```
$("#crop-mini").Jcrop({
        onChange : updatePositions,
        onSelect : updatePositions,
        boxWidth : 500,
        boxHeight : 400,
        keySupport : false,
        setSelect : [0, 0, 999999, 999999],
        minSize : [10, 10]
});
```

Where #crop-mini is the `<img>` tag containing the image. `updatePositions` is just a function that... updates the selection positions. Pretty straightforward:

```
function updatePositions(coords)
{
    $(".x").val(coords.x);
    $(".y").val(coords.y);
    $(".w").val(coords.w);
    $(".h").val(coords.h);
};
```

I upload an image, write its url into the `<img>` tag, fire a fancybox and call JCrop. However, when I resize the selection box, boom, this glitch appears:

[image]

It looks like the selected content shows the same image being deformed from positions `coords.y` (`coords` is the current selection position) to `coords.h+coords.y`, and from `0` to `coords.w`. If I put the selection touching the left corner, you would see the whole image.

By the way, cropping works as expected, and the real coordinates are being passed, so I happen to think that **the problem is within the presentation, not the processing**. Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have `max-width` set in your css:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

Just add the following rule to fix it:

```
.image-version img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Where `.image-version` is a css class of the element wrapping `<img>` with id `#crop-mini`.

Comment: Amazing, I can't imagine the reason, but it works. Do you have any idea why is this working?

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday and found the conflict in the styling. Although I don't know the internals of this plugin, so can't further explain why.

Comment: well, that's enough to me. Thanks!